# Configuring emacs 24 -- delete original symlinks?

Tags: macos, emacs, installation

Installed emacs 24 and do my best to rid myself of the Mac OSX preinstalled version.

I think I've already gotten rid of everything correctly (and learning about [El Capitan's rootless feature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really/193379) along the way) by running the following

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/emacs
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/emacs
```

Now's the time to remove old symlinks, but I thought I'd do a sanity check before doing so.  Which symlinks do I delete? End goal is to be able to run the latest `emacsclient` by default:

```
# This is what I want to be default
$ /usr/local/bin/emacsclient -t
/usr/local/bin/emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
/usr/local/bin/emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

  --socket-name
  --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
  --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)

# here is /usr/local... which should I delete?
$ ls /usr/local/bin | grep emacs
emacs
emacs-24.5
emacsclient

# and here is /usr/bin... (not sure the difference)
$ ls /usr/bin | grep emacs
emacs
emacs-undumped
emacsclient

# need to change below to latest emacs...
# ---------------------------------------
$ which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs

$ which emacsclient
/usr/bin/emacsclient

$ emacsclient -t
emacsclient: invalid option -- t
Try `emacsclient --help' for more information
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove a system component? Installing your own alongside works fine, and you don't need to fight the system (to remove upgrades as they arrive, fix things whick break when you removed too much, etc).

Comment: How about just putting a complete prepackaged version of Emacs into your Application directory and use the path to the executable?  http://emacsformacosx.com/  Then, remove all the old Emacs stuff or leave it -- but at least there's no longer a question of which symlink to delete -- i.e., delete it all or leave it all, whichever floats your boat -- your new installation of Emacs is in a completely different place in one nice and neat bundle ending in `.app` - i.e., `Emacs.app`